# Noise reduction using histograms in opencv

Tags: opencv

I want to implement a simple noise correction scheme for RGB images. The image contain some garbage pixels at random locations. So, I am thinking of doing this:

1. Segment the image.
2. Calculate histograms for each segment.
3. Analyze the histogram and dump the pixels which are negligible in histogram distribution over a segment.

I am using openCV. I have implemented steps 1 and 2, but I am not able to find out the number of pixels in each histogram bin. Please help

Comment: which language do you use?

Comment: I am using opencv in c/c++

Comment: How have you calculated histogram for segment (it may have arbitrary size and shape)? Do you use OpenCV CalcHist or write algorithm of calculation by yourself?

Answer (score 0):

In order to analyze a histogram, you have to make a few assumptions about it. One good assumption is that the histogram will be roughly modeled as noise + gaussian bell curves.

Check this out.

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithm
```

Finding the roots of the derivative function of the histogram will give you the location of the peaks. You can then find the boundaries of each peak, possibly by finding the roots of the second derivative function.

After you identify the location and span of the histogram peaks, you can classify pixels as being signal or noise pixels.